# (org-do-promote) on keyboards without arrow keys

Tags: org-mode

I'm using a keyboard without arrow keys because well... its Emacs!

However, I realized that (org-do-promote) is bound to M-left.

I find it hard to accept this 'tragic' situation ;D

Do I really have to custom global-set-key this?

Ideas on keybindings are also very welcome

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org does provide some extra bindings "for TTY access". They are on by default only if `window-system` is nil, but otherwise disabled. However, you can enable them manually by setting `org-use-extra-keys` to non-nil *before loading Org*.

With `org-use-extra-keys`, you can use `C-c C-x l`/`C-c C-x r`, which are also bound to `org-metaleft`/`org-metaright` in `org-mode-map`.

Comment: Thanks for the input :D However, `C-c C-x l` & `C-c C-x r` doesn't seem to work for me... Having a quick look at `C-h v org-mode-map`, I found `org-metaleft` solely bound to `M-left` (taking a look at the variable helped a lot tho) Or was the answer an idea on making custom keybindings?

Comment: No, I was not suggesting you do new bindings, those are set by default for me, I did not create them. But damn it, this binding is reported on my `C-h k M-<right>`, (I use helpful). And they don't work out of the box for me too. So, I checked `org-keys.el` and it seems you may need extra steps, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Customized the variable to `non-nil` and got it working :D I wonder what list of extra bindings are added tho... `C-c C-x u` seem to be `org-metaup` but I can't seem to find the binding for `org-metadown` (which is odd) Accepted the answer because my original question is fully answered - thanks!

Comment: To check the full list, take a look at `org-keys.el` and search for `org-use-extra-keys`. ;-)

Comment: Aha! thank you very much ;D